# Kohler courage 27hp bogs down

Tags: lawn-mower

Kohler courage 27hp cub cadet starts and runs fine for awhile, time varies, then bogs down like I'm running at half throttle. Then magically runs normal for awhile, again length of time varies. This keeps repeating throughout my mowing cycle. I'm thinking a weak coil but just guessing. New carb, new plugs, new fuel lines and filter.

Comment: the symptoms sounds like a thermal issue to me. if it doesn't throttle down when running idle for the same amount of time as it would when mowing, that would be another indication of heat build-up.

Comment: Is the deck getting clogged with loads of wet grass?

Comment: When you changed everything did you dump the bowl on the carb? Water in the carb can cause problems similar to yours.

Comment: Did you purge the system of old fuel and fill up with fresh fuel? My neighbor had a chainsaw that wouldn't stay powered to save his life; bogged down to half throttle like you describe. He dumped the old fuel and filled it up fresh and after getting through the residual line fuel it was stable.